# Seaborn lineplot. Vertical line before and after 1945 from a dataset

Tags: python, seaborn

Will need a bit of help placing a vertical line in this seaborn lineplot. The line should separate the population before and after 1945. The line should also keep the current graph in place without moving the data.

Here is the code and image of the lineplot.

```
sns.lineplot(x="year", y="population",
             hue="region",
             data=japan_pop, ci=None)
plt.title('Population', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

[Lineplot I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoQMv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the axvline method of matplotlib:

```
plt.axvline(1945,0,max(japan_pop.population))
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I thought I tried that one, but I guess I was wrong